# Как записывать обновляющийся словарь в CSV?

Tags: python, csv

Есть словарь, который нужно записать в CSV.

Сам словарь:

```
{'custom': False, 'chart_mode': 1, 'select': True, 'visible': True, 'session_deals': 0, 'session_buy_orders': 0, 'session_sell_orders': 0, 'volume': 1, 'volumehigh': 16, 'volumelow': 1, 'time': 1608611959, 'digits': 2, 'spread': 1, 'spread_float': True, 'ticks_bookdepth': 32, 'trade_calc_mode': 33, 'trade_mode': 4, 'start_time': 0, 'expiration_time': 0, 'trade_stops_level': 0, 'trade_freeze_level': 0, 'trade_exemode': 2, 'swap_mode': 0, 'swap_rollover3days': 3, 'margin_hedged_use_leg': False, 'expiration_mode': 15, 'filling_mode': 3, 'order_mode': 127, 'order_gtc_mode': 0, 'option_mode': 0, 'option_right': 0, 'bid': 47.66, 'bidhigh': 47.87, 'bidlow': 47.59, 'ask': 47.67, 'askhigh': 47.88, 'asklow': 47.6, 'last': 47.67, 'lasthigh': 47.88, 'lastlow': 47.59, 'volume_real': 1.0, 'volumehigh_real': 16.0, 'volumelow_real': 1.0, 'option_strike': 0.0, 'point': 0.01, 'trade_tick_value': 10.0, 'trade_tick_value_profit': 10.0, 'trade_tick_value_loss': 10.0, 'trade_tick_size': 0.01, 'trade_contract_size': 1.0, 'trade_accrued_interest': 0.0, 'trade_face_value': 0.0, 'trade_liquidity_rate': 0.0, 'volume_min': 1.0, 'volume_max': 1000.0, 'volume_step': 1.0, 'volume_limit': 0.0, 'swap_long': 0.0, 'swap_short': 0.0, 'margin_initial': 1000.0, 'margin_maintenance': 1000.0, 'session_volume': 0.0, 'session_turnover': 0.0, 'session_interest': 0.0, 'session_buy_orders_volume': 0.0, 'session_sell_orders_volume': 0.0, 'session_open': 0.0, 'session_close': 0.0, 'session_aw': 0.0, 'session_price_settlement': 0.0, 'session_price_limit_min': 0.0, 'session_price_limit_max': 0.0, 'margin_hedged': 0.0, 'price_change': 0.0, 'price_volatility': 0.0, 'price_theoretical': 0.0, 'price_greeks_delta': 0.0, 'price_greeks_theta': 0.0, 'price_greeks_gamma': 0.0, 'price_greeks_vega': 0.0, 'price_greeks_rho': 0.0, 'price_greeks_omega': 0.0, 'price_sensitivity': 0.0, 'basis': 'CLE', 'category': '', 'currency_base': 'USD', 'currency_profit': 'USD', 'currency_margin': 'USD', 'bank': '', 'description': 'Crude Light (Globex)', 'exchange': '', 'formula': '', 'isin': '', 'name': '@CLE', 'page': '', 'path': 'Exchange-Futures\\@CLE'}
```

На выходе хочу получить таблицу, где ключи - это заголовок столбца, а значения - это строка столбца. При каждом запросе значения словаря меняются.

Как реализовать запись так, чтобы ключи были заголовками столбца, а значения строками, и далее, добавлять новые строки с теми же значениями ключей?

Comment: Пожалуйста, раскройте вот эту фразу в вопросе - _при каждом запросе словаря значения меняются_, более подробно. В связи с чем и как значения меняются?

Comment: есть данные, которые приходят в виде словаря, ключи одни и те же, значения другие. К примеру выше ** 'chart_mode' : 1, - при след запросе значение = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по вашим предыдущим вопросам, вы читаете данные в цикле из WEB API по одной строке (строка данных приходит в виде словаря).

В таких условиях эффективнее всего накапливать словари (строки данных) в список и сохранять накопленные данные в БД пакетами по N записей. Другие ответы не учитывают особенности получения данных. Добавление записей в Pandas DataFrame по одной - очень медленная и неэффективная операция. Добавление DataFrame (`df1.append(df2)`) - работает еще медленнее и делать это в цикле крайне неэффективно.

Я бы решал вашу задачу так:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

db_filename = "/tmp/db.sqlite"

row_count = 0
batch_size = 10000
data = []

db_conn = sqlite3.connect(db_filename)

while time.time() < tempo:
    symbol_info = mt5.symbol_info('@CLE')
    if symbol_info:        
        data.append(symbol_info._asdict())
        row_count += 1
        if row_count == batch_size:
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            df.to_sql("data", db_conn, if_exists="append")
            row_count = 0
            data = []
```

чтение данных из БД

```
db_filename = "/tmp/db.sqlite"
db_conn = sqlite3.connect(db_filename)
d = pd.read_sql("select * from data", db_conn)
print(d.head())
```

Comment: спасибо... учту в будующем своем обучении... бд еще не изучал

Comment: Метод для записи в бд очень крутой и пишет данные оч быстро, рекомендую!

Answer (score 2):

воспользуйтесь модулем `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

my_dict={'custom': False, 'chart_mode': 1, 'select': True, 'visible': True, 'session_deals': 0, 'session_buy_orders': 0, 'session_sell_orders': 0, 'volume': 1, 'volumehigh': 16, 'volumelow': 1, 'time': 1608611959, 'digits': 2, 'spread': 1, 'spread_float': True, 'ticks_bookdepth': 32, 'trade_calc_mode': 33, 'trade_mode': 4, 'start_time': 0, 'expiration_time': 0, 'trade_stops_level': 0, 'trade_freeze_level': 0, 'trade_exemode': 2, 'swap_mode': 0, 'swap_rollover3days': 3, 'margin_hedged_use_leg': False, 'expiration_mode': 15, 'filling_mode': 3, 'order_mode': 127, 'order_gtc_mode': 0, 'option_mode': 0, 'option_right': 0, 'bid': 47.66, 'bidhigh': 47.87, 'bidlow': 47.59, 'ask': 47.67, 'askhigh': 47.88, 'asklow': 47.6, 'last': 47.67, 'lasthigh': 47.88, 'lastlow': 47.59, 'volume_real': 1.0, 'volumehigh_real': 16.0, 'volumelow_real': 1.0, 'option_strike': 0.0, 'point': 0.01, 'trade_tick_value': 10.0, 'trade_tick_value_profit': 10.0, 'trade_tick_value_loss': 10.0, 'trade_tick_size': 0.01, 'trade_contract_size': 1.0, 'trade_accrued_interest': 0.0, 'trade_face_value': 0.0, 'trade_liquidity_rate': 0.0, 'volume_min': 1.0, 'volume_max': 1000.0, 'volume_step': 1.0, 'volume_limit': 0.0, 'swap_long': 0.0, 'swap_short': 0.0, 'margin_initial': 1000.0, 'margin_maintenance': 1000.0, 'session_volume': 0.0, 'session_turnover': 0.0, 'session_interest': 0.0, 'session_buy_orders_volume': 0.0, 'session_sell_orders_volume': 0.0, 'session_open': 0.0, 'session_close': 0.0, 'session_aw': 0.0, 'session_price_settlement': 0.0, 'session_price_limit_min': 0.0, 'session_price_limit_max': 0.0, 'margin_hedged': 0.0, 'price_change': 0.0, 'price_volatility': 0.0, 'price_theoretical': 0.0, 'price_greeks_delta': 0.0, 'price_greeks_theta': 0.0, 'price_greeks_gamma': 0.0, 'price_greeks_vega': 0.0, 'price_greeks_rho': 0.0, 'price_greeks_omega': 0.0, 'price_sensitivity': 0.0, 'basis': 'CLE', 'category': '', 'currency_base': 'USD', 'currency_profit': 'USD', 'currency_margin': 'USD', 'bank': '', 'description': 'Crude Light (Globex)', 'exchange': '', 'formula': '', 'isin': '', 'name': '@CLE', 'page': '', 'path': 'Exchange-Futures\\@CLE'}
filename = "test.csv"

if os.path.exists("test.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
    df = df.append(my_dict, ignore_index=True)    
else:
    df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict, index=[0])

df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

Comment: выдает ошибку File "C:/Users/neket/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/MT5 CODE/connect.py", line 39, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)

Comment: все работает, моя ошибка... не переименовал файл в конце

Answer (score 1):

Я реализовал простой класс `CsvAdder`, пример его использования ниже:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##bVJNb4MwDL3zKyz1AEgUqe0OU6Udpm23acftiLLEtNFogpK0tJr225kDpQ0tOfDh52c/P6c@ua1Wq7blFbMWXuzhWQg06wjoCCyhKKSSrigSi1WZQanYDtMe9sdH8xKeQNeokg7NIG7iDFBxLaTaEBbvXTl/jNMxqyHkQyu8tGJCnLuIoIMsh3Rpu/wr1MG7WhsH3B5G4UsHAvJXyd2XkQ5N0uulOSRWwqu1lFNJ6xKR/@DJJmmaThTKG0/fIiNvkts5etDoJhHpZRheaYtduzu38h5LA49RUYGzyUG@Qbc3qqOFycdgIS6DAz3NbZehRzSDtyPb1RWCLmFv2QZ9bO4PfDIjmXKw6P@jiDOyY7gESezQupwcjLs6FCTfjHWki2sjIkHJvzGL17CgpX/Te/lHJXK/SLJiBu@MxvJ7JU1cq5CxOjMeQob/DISPRS4HkY1020mRwCxw1hsxIbdzcEqyB64ievad9DE7kD9it@0/)

```
class CsvAdder:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.f = open(fname, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
        self.w = None
    def add(self, d):
        if self.w is None:
            import csv
            self.w = csv.DictWriter(self.f, fieldnames = list(d.keys()))
            self.w.writeheader()
        self.w.writerow(d)
    def close(self):
        self.f.close()
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, t, v, tr):
        self.close()

# Example of usage

# ----- Variant 1 -----

ca = CsvAdder('test.csv')

# Add first record
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
ca.add(d)
# Later add second
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
ca.add(d)

ca.close()

# ----- Variant 2 -----

with CsvAdder('test.csv') as ca:
    # Add first record
    d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    ca.add(d)
    # Later add second
    d = {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
    ca.add(d)
```

Выходной файл:

```
a,b
1,2
3,4
```